# Estimate truncation point of truncated normal given the mean and variance of the distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

If we know the pre-truncated distribution follows the standard normal distribution and we know the post-truncated mean and variance, is it possible to calculate the truncated point of the truncated normal?

From Wikipedia, it seems like we can express the mean of the truncated normal as (if my derivation is correct)
$$
E(X|a<X<b) = \frac{2}{2\pi}\frac{exp(-\frac{1}{2}a^2)-exp(-\frac{1}{2}b^2)}{erf(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}})-erf(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})}
$$

and the variance of the truncated normal as

$$
Var(X|a<X<b) = 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{a\times exp(-\frac{1}{2}a^2)-b\times exp(-\frac{1}{2}b^2)}{erf(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}})-erf(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})}-E(X|a<X<b)^2
$$

As I am not familiar with the error function, is it possible for us to estimate $a$ and $b$ given $E(X|a<X<b)$ and $Var(X|a<X<b)$? If that's impossible, is it possible for us to estimate only $b$ if we assume $a$ is known?

The thing is, considering this is from standard normal distribution, we can iterate all possible combination of $a$ and $b$ and get a table for comparison. But is there any more elegant methods for the calculation?

Comment: But we are assuming the original distribution follows the standard normal distribution, therefore we know the $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. In that case, isn't that we only need to estimate 2 parameters (1 if we assume we know one of the truncation point) with two pieces of information?

Comment: ... you're right, I missed the "standard" part somehow, and I've deleted my comment.